# Select from dropdown list in flask

Tags: python, mongodb, web, flask

I'm very new to Flask and web development and am having some trouble with generating a list from a mongdb query and passing that through to the html template to be in a dropdown menu in Flask.

Please see the current code below:

views.py

```
from flask import render_template
from app import app
from pymongo import MongoClient

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')

def index():

user = {'name': 'Bob'}

client = MongoClient()

client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/')
db = client.test_database
db = client['test-database']

collection = db.test_collection
posts = db.posts
name_list = []

for post in posts.find({'type': "server"}):
    name_list.append(post['name'])

# Get selected option and save into variable?
#if:
#        choice = x.option

return render_template("index.html",
                       title='Database selector',
                       user = 'Bob',
                       server_list=name_list)
```

server_list contains: 
[u'server1', u'server2', u'server3']

index.html template

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>{{ title }} - Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hi, {{ user }}!</h1>


      <h2>Option selector</h2>
        <h3><table><form action="" method="POST">
          <td>
          <label>Select :</label>
            <select name="option" width="300px">
            {% for x in server_list %}
            <option value="{{ x.option }}" SELECTED>{{ x.option }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
            </select>
          </td>

        </form></table></h3>


  </body>
</html>
```

Firstly, the select list does not get populated and secondly, would anyone have a kind suggestions on how to capture the result of the selection so I can use this in another database query and generate a second dropdown list?

Any hints greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You are making a pretty simple error. I'll give you some additional cleanup advice here as well. Ultimately your reference to `x.option` is incorrect in your Jinja syntax. Since it is a simple list you should just use `x` (it has no `option` property). Do not forget to use endfor and endif clauses.

**Python:**

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    user = {'name': 'Bob'}

    client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/')
    db = client['test-database']

    collection = db.test_collection
    posts = db.posts
    name_list = [p['name'] for p in posts.find({'type': "server"})]

    return render_template("index.html",
                           title='Database selector',
                           user='Bob',
                           server_list=name_list)
```

**Jinja/HTML:**

```
{% for x in server_list %}
<option value="{{ x }}"{% if loop.first %} SELECTED{% endif %}>{{ x }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you PJ Santoro.. - this has been very helpful - As a continuation I would like to pass the result of the selection back to the code to make a new database query and then have that populate a second drop-down box on the same page. I have code like this for the python and jinja.. however the submitted value is not being returned correctly - would you have further thoughts please?

Comment: if request.form['submit'] == 'myselect':
        choice = x
        sub_name_list = [q['sub_server'] for q in posts.find({'type': choice})]

    return render_template("index.html",
                           title='Database selector',
                           user='Bob',
                           server_list=name_list,
                           sub_server_list=sub_name_list)

Comment: <td>
            <label>Select2 :</label>
              <select name="option" id="sub_myselect" onchange="this.form.submit()">
              {% for y in sub_server_list %}
              <option value="{{ y }}"{% if loop.first %} SELECTED{% endif %}>{{ y }}</option>
              {% endfor %}
          </td>

Comment: If you want further assistance I recommend asking a new question with a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) rather than inserting a bunch of code into the comments.